# How to display number of rows in a sql table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get lines' number from the result of the sql query, so I started by connecting to the database, then checking if the connection was established and finally I tried to count the number of lines, here's the code :

```
 <?php   
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db_test";
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
        $res = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT (id_offre) AS nb FROM offres');
        
        $data = $res->fetch();
        
        $nb = $data['nb'];
        
        echo $nb;
?>
```

I get these errors :

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean
>
> Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

I used echo to check the 'nb' value, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your query fails which makes `$conn->query()` to return `false`.

**So, why does the query fail?**

SQL doesn't allow for any spaces between function names and the parentheses, like you have at `COUNT ()`.

So if you change:

```
SELECT COUNT (id_offre) AS nb FROM offres
```

to

```
SELECT COUNT(id_offre) AS nb FROM offres
```

...it should work.

*Note:* I would highly recommend you to have a read about [`mysqli::error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and add some error handling to your code.

Comment: I tried this `$res = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM offres');` and this  `$data = mysqli_num_rows($res);`  I no longer get the error but it gives me a false result, It gives 1 but i do have 4 lines in my table

Comment: @B.Mayssa - I can't answer that since I haven't seen your database and tables. If this solved your initial issue you posted about, feel free to mark it as accepted. If you have other issues (like the one you now mentioned), please make a new question where you include all that information (like example data etc).

Comment: @B.Mayssa - When you do a `SELECT COUNT(what-ever) FROM ...`, you will only get one single row back from the database. Instead of using `num_rows()`, you need to check the value `nb` that you got back from the database. It's just like you've done it in your question.

Comment: @B.Mayssa I agree with Magnus here. You haven't provided us with relevant information about the database in order to provide you with a solution. Magnus' answer IMHO does answer it. You asked to use `COUNT()` and it was provided to you. Now you say it doesn't return all results; your question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php   
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db_test";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (! $conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
    }
    $res = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM offres');
    $data_count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    echo($data_count);

?>
```

check this out!

Comment: Personally I feel that this answer even though accepted is 1) another form of "try this" (*check this out!*) and 2) it didn't answer the question as posted.